# I need to update existing foreign key, but I can't drop it in order to update it

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I've got a migration to correct existing foreign key, it looks like this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('content_term', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('content_term_content_id_foreign');
        $table->foreign('content_id')->references('id')->on('content')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

The original table and foregin key looked like this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('content_term', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('content_id')->unsigned();
        $table->unsignedInteger('term_id');

        $table->foreign('content_id')->references('id')->on('content')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreign('term_id')->references('id')->on('terms')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    });
}
```

I forgot to add onDelete('cascade') for content_id foreign key creation and need to correct that in a new migration.

When I run php artisan migrate with thew latest migration I've added I get this

[image]

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'content_term_content_id_foreign'; check that column/key exists (SQL: alter table `content_term` drop foreign key `content_term_content_id_foreign`)

MYSQL complains that the foreign key does not exist in content_term table. When I check that table using phpmyadmin I can clearly see that key exists. See attached pic for proof of that.

[image]

What's the problem with my new migration, why is this line causing a problem:

```
$table->dropForeign('content_term_content_id_foreign');
```

Comment: Not sure this will help, but you could try the "alternate" way using an array of only the column name: `$table->dropForeign(['content_id']);`

Comment: getting the same error with array

Comment: managed to solve it somehow, not sure what was really the issue. I did migrate:fresh and generated the migration again, now suddenly it works... hope it will work in production

Comment: Wow, you planing to run `migrate:fresh` in production? Try chain `change()` on improved foreing key constrain

Comment: It seems my issue was only local, when I deployed to production it just worked, no problems with foreign key. It seems that locally for what ever reason something went out of sync, so migratre:fresh reseted things. In prod migrate alone just worked...